# Steam OpenId invalid signature InternalOpenIDError:

Tags: node.js, passport.js, steam, steamworks-api

After installing and having the passport authentication working properly for a while (something like a year in 2017)
I run again this project in 2019 and I got the following error message when authenticating with Steam and passport

```
{
  "name": "InternalOpenIDError",
  "message": "Failed to verify assertion",
  "openidError": {
    "message": "Invalid signature"
  }
}
```

This is the configuration I had, and it's always returning the URL `/#/404`, since it's giving an error and redirecting

```
app.get(/^\/auth\/steam(\/return)?$/,
    passport.authenticate('steam', { failureRedirect: '/#/404' }), (req, res) => {
        res.redirect('/');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the authentication that was implemented by steam changed in April 2018 and they included HTTPS in the protocol.

The library `passport-steam` has adapted this in order to work, but of course, I was runnning in the old version (1.0.8) when I was building and installing `node_modules` in my app.

Bumping the version in my packaje.json to `"passport-steam": "^1.0.10",` fixed it for me with exactly the same code running in the application.